# Debug python API Visual Studio Code

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, visual-studio-code, uwsgi

I try to debug a project written with Python which uses uWSGI as an application server. It runs like

```
uwsgi --pythonpath $PROJECT_PATH
```

Is it possible to add breakpoints and debug the project with VS Code?

Comment: were you able to do it?

Comment: Unfortunately not.